# Android Bootloop No recovery mode - only viberation

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, bootloader

Phone: Huawei honor 3c

I downloaded Emotion UI 3.0 for "probably" the wrong set form here [offical site](http://emui.huawei.com/plugin.php?id=hwdownload).But it was installed properly. Then there was an update of same emotion UI, which on installation put the phone in bootloop on restart. This is what phone does

- On pressing power button, it vibrates without going into recovery mode or showing logo - just a black screen
- The phone vibrates after every 15-20 seconds, which is probably an indication that it is restarting again and agian
- Pressing Power button/volume up/down keeps does not make any difference
- Partition is not shown in my computer (when connected to laptop)
- Using ADB: Command adb devices or adb wait-for-device do not list any device
- Windows device manager shows "MediaTek PreLoader USB VCOM(Android)(COM5)" under Ports (COM & LPT) which indicates that phone is detected but before anything happens it reboots
  [image]

I've gone through several threads on this topic and nothing helped.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to browse Chinese/Russian sites is this: Instead of browsing the url directly, you put the url in the Google search, then click that small link called "Translate this page" besides that link in the result! You would have not made a mistake and selected the proper ROM for your device.

Coming back to the topic, I've flashed stock ROM on two MediaTek based phones recently and based on the symptoms (VCOM USB Driver appearing and disappearing), I can suggest you to first download the correct ROM for your device [from here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/guide-huawei-honor-3c-h30-u10-t2837773) (Look down in the section called **SP Flash Tool Flashable ROM**) and then use the [SPFlash Tool](http://spflashtool.com) to flash it.

If you keep the SPFlash Tool open before inserting the USB cable, the tool will detect the phone and start communicating on the VCOM port and the connection will be stable. After that, you can flash the ROM back to your device.

**Note:** This is going to wipe your phone completely and erase any existing data on it. If your phone is totally hard-bricked, I can't think of any way of recovering the data unless you take it to the service center.

Answer (score 0):

Try USB JIG:

Had a issue like yours. I have heard of USB jig but couldn't find any all around Nepal. I tired by myself (finding easy guides via internet). At this first attempt I could n't. Maybe I wasn't that good. But Maybe you can find around to buy or (ebay/amazon). I think it would most probably work for your case.

Answer (score -1):

Take out your battery for 15 seconds and then try booting it into recovery (power + vol down or power + home + vol down) Hope this helps

Comment: did that already .. no , its not working

Comment: You might want to check out riff JTAG box